# I want find records use operator like this : field&16

Tags: sequelize.js

I want find records use operator like this : field&16

node.js project use sequelize

```sql
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `slot` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES 
(1,127,'a'),
(2,96,'b'),
(3,63,'c'),
(4,44,'c');
```

I want models.MyTable.findAll({where:...})

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE slot&16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People here are unfriendly,

```
models.MyTable.findAll({where:literal(`slot&${slot}`)})
```